trying to test pump?
I have a 30' deep seep well, with a submersible it had a 2 wire 230V pump and a pumptec no load sensor, it quit working and i have a 4 wire 1hp 230V pump i'm wanting to connect, can I wire it directly to power with out a control box or no load sensor and turn it on and off manually?

With appropriate caution, and for a short time, bench testing should be fine. Since it is probably using the water to cool itself, you wouldn't want to run it for very long without giving it water to work on.
